# Finding an Element in List c++

Tags: c++, list, find

I am trying to find an element in a list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list> 

using namespace std;

class Testing {
public: 
Testing();
}

list<Testing> Testing_List;

Testing Testing_Object;

auto List_Index = find(Testing_List.begin(), Testing_List.end(), Testing_Object);
```

It gave me the Error message

```
Semantic Issue. Invalid Operands to binary expression 


template <class _InputIterator, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_InputIterator
find(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const _Tp& __value_)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (*__first == __value_)
            break;
    return __first;
}
```

Presumably it's because there's no proper comparison operator== defined for the Testing class. So what I did was to try to define the == operator for the Testing class like this:

```
bool operator==(const Testing & lhs, const Testing & rhs) {
    return &lhs == &rhs;
}
```

Still no luck! Can you please tell me what's wrong? How should I go about finding the element in that list of Testing objects?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Also, you will never find `Testing_Object` inside `Testing_List` using that definition of `operator==`.

Comment: @john oops, I didn't see that : )

Comment: @becko. Thanks, I included the error message in the question above.

Comment: I assume you're doing `Testing_List.push_back(Testing_Object);` and then expecting to find it? In that case the `&lhs == &rhs` test will never work, since `push_back` makes a copy of the object - the addresses will be different. You need to work out some other way of comparing objects based on something other than their addresses.

Comment: @JonathanPotter. You're right, thanks. So what's the best way to compare two objects in this situation? Let's say if I use an array of pointers to the Testing objects instead, how can I find the index of a certain object in the array?

Comment: @JonathanPotter. FYI - What I wanted to do here was to locate that certain object in the container (be it a list or an array), and then delete it when prompted. Thanks!

Comment: @Newbie, C++ always copies things around (in some sophisticated manners). `Testing_Object` will never have the same memory address as the objects inside the list.

Comment: @Newbie: The best way depends on the definition of the objects in question. For the `Testing` object you've shown above, there's no way at all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter. Thank you so much. I guess I should change it to list<Testing *>

Comment: @Newbie I wonder that someone who working on MySQL, C++, Java, Python is called Newbie.:) I think it is a professional.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this operator

```
bool operator==(const Testing & lhs, const Testing & rhs) {
    return &lhs == &rhs;
}
```

does not make sense for the container and the searched element declared like

```
list<Testing> Testing_List;

Testing Testing_Object;
```

because it compares addresses of elements in the list with the address of the local variable that evidently are different for all elements of the list. You could use this operator if you know the address of some element in the list.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class Testing 
{
public: 
    Testing() = default;
};

bool operator==(const Testing & lhs, const Testing & rhs) {
    return &lhs == &rhs;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    std::list<Testing> Testing_List;
    Testing *sixthElement;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        Testing_List.push_back( Testing() );
        if ( i + 1 == 6 ) sixthElement = &Testing_List.back();
    }

    auto it = std::find( Testing_List.begin(), Testing_List.end(), *sixthElement );

    if ( it != Testing_List.end() ) std::cout << "Wow, the sixth element is found!" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "It is the end of the World" << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
Wow, the sixth element is found!
```

However there is no great sense to use such an approach.

You should define some properties in your class and use them to compare objects of the class. In this case you should not use pointers in the body of the operator.

For example

```
class Testing 
{
public: 
    Testing( int i = 0 ) aProperty( i ) {}
    int getProperty() const { return aProperty; }
private:
    int aProperty;
};

bool operator ==( const Testing &lhs, const Testing &rhs ) 
{
    return lhs.getProperty() == rhs.getProperty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was putting `operator==` inside the Testing class. It should be a global function.

```
bool operator==(const Testing & lhs, const Testing & rhs) {
    return &lhs == &rhs;
}
```

I'm ignoring your actual definition of `operator==`, I'll assume you know what you're doing.

Comment: That seems like a rather bold assumption :)

Comment: @john. Thanks! I tried your suggestion but the old problem lingers. Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what the old problem is. But the issue you seem to be having is that you don't know what equality means for your Testing object. That obviously makes it hard to find anything as you don't know when two objects are the same.

Comment: @Newbie: What exactly is "the old problem"? The code compiles, so that's step one. Could you post the complete code of your test case, please. It could well be that the problem is what Vlad Feinstein already pointed out. You are comparing pointers to two objects, not if they contain an equivalent value. So with your current code, you most likely never find a given object.